# Visual Basic Project fails to update Microsoft Access database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, oledb

I have created a database that holds 3 values, the ID, UserName, and Score. I need to create a new entry to this database when the save button is clicked. My program needs to create a new row with the Username and score provided by the application.

This is my code to update an existing database:

```
Private Sub ButtonSaveScore_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonSaveScore.Click

    provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="
    dataFile = "F:\Documents\Class Documents\CSC289 - K6A - Programming Capstone Project\Project\Scoreboard.accdb"
    connString = provider & dataFile
    myConnection.ConnectionString = connString


    Using con As New OleDbConnection(connString),
  cmd As New OleDbCommand("UPDATE [Scores] SET [UserName] = ?, [Score] = ? WHERE [ID] = ?", con)

        con.Open()

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", OleDbType.Char).Value = "NEW"
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", OleDbType.Char).Value = playerName
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Score", OleDbType.Char).Value = wins


        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    End Using

End Sub
```

I get

> oledb exception was unhandled

It highlights `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` and says ***data criteria mismatch***.

Can someone give me advice to get this working?

Comment: wild guess --- Score should be numeric  ... maybe OleDbType.Integer

Comment: `@ID` is assigned as Char, but you write a string in it. Please check your OleDbTypes. I guess, `@ID` and `@UserName` should be a VarChar/String and `@Score` a Int32.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of issues there.  Firstly, at least one of your parameters is the wrong data type.  Secondly, your parameters are in the wrong order.

The Jet and ACE OLE DB providers only partially support named parameters, in that they allow you to use names so that your code can be clearer but they ignore the names and just use the positions.  That means that you need to add the parameters to your `OleDbCommand` in the same order as they appear in the SQL code.  You're not doing that so you have one issue there, although that's not the direct cause of your error message.

Even if those providers did fully support named parameters though, you're not using names in your SQL code.  That means that there would be no way to match up parameters by name anyway, so how did you think that adding them in the wrong order wouldn't be an issue?

Given that all three of your parameters are specified as the same data type though, the incorrect order would not cause the error message you're seeing.  If that data type was correct, you'd just find that the wrong data was saved to some of the columns, which would be even worse, i.e. appearing to work but not rather than just failing.  You need to make sure that you use the correct `OleDbType` value for the column you're trying to save to.  If your `ID` column in the database is specified to contain 32-bit numbers then you should be using `OleDbType.Integer` for the corresponding parameters.  I'd also suggest using `VarChar` rather than `Char` unless your column is specifically fixed-width, which a `Text` column in Access is unlikely to be and I'm not sure even can be.